# Derivative given separate constant for given function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

I do not understand what is meant here.

I must find the equation of the tangent line to a graph at $x = 0$ given the following function:

$y = 3e^x − 7x$

How do I compute this problem?

Comment: What don't you understand? This is as straightforward an exercise as they come.

Comment: This can help you. 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/Tangents_Rates.aspx

Comment: Is your trouble with calculating the derivative $y'(x)$, or you know how to calculate derivative and you have problems with writing the equation of the tangent line (or both)? (EDIT: Now I see that my comment is a few months late. I should have looked at the date question was posted - the fact that it was recently bumped was what made me ask this comment. Still, even if the question is not new, adding some details into the question could improve it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're starting with $y=3e^x-7x$. The derivative will give you, at every point, the slope of the tangent line to that point.

So you first need to find the derivative.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 3e^x-7$$

When you plug in an x-value to this, it's going to give you the slope of the tangent line. So, we're trying to find the slope at $x=0$, so we plug in $0$ for $x$.

Then you're going to want to use the linearization formula:

$$y = f'(k)(x-k)+f(k)$$

Where k is the x-value where you're trying to find the tangent line.

So when you plug in $x=0$, that's giving you $f'(k)$, which is $-4$.

You should be able to plug in from there.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

The slope of the tangent line at a point is given by the value of the derivative at the point. So since, in your function $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=3e^{x}-7$$
The value at $x=0$ (which is the slope) is $-4$.

Comment: It's probably best to give some hints rather than just give the answer.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I think that it's more clear to give an answer to the OP.

Comment: It's also more efficient for homework cheating. Better to tease out the real issue.

Comment: @symplectomorphic OK. I edited.

Comment: "The value, and thus the slope of the derivative" should be "the value of the derivative, and thus the slope of the tangent line."

Comment: @symplectomorphic Done.

Comment: Giving a direct answer helps me work recursively to note where I went wrong. I appreciate the input though.

Comment: @Donnie If you already tried something, I think it's best if you add that to the answer.

Comment: Okay then. Will do.